# Android Bluetooth example & OBEX

Tags: android, bluetooth, obex

I have a device which only support the OBEX Object Push Protocol. I want to transmit data from this device to my android device. After hours for reading, testing and frustration, I hope someone @ StackOverflow can help me out. So here it goes:

What I figured out:

1. I need to implement an server functionality in my android app.
2. Since I know the `MAC` address of the device I can connect directly to this device.

Can I use the Bluetooth classes in Android SDK to solve my problem? Because the phone should only pair with the device, connect and transmit data. I can't figure out anywhere whenever the Bluetooth classes in the Android SDK supports the OBEX Protocol.

Can I use the `Bluetooth chat example` to establish a connection between the phone and the device and transmit data? Does anyone have an example of how to write the server-side for listening to ports/channels and retrieving data? I have googled all week after a solution, so I am very greatful if someone knows how I can accomplish this task.

This is the output describing the bluetooth profiles of my device:

```
# sdptool browse  C0:1B:DC:1F:E2:F1
Browsing C0:1B:DC:1F:E2:F1 ...
Service Name: OBEX Object Push
Service RecHandle: 0x10000
Service Class ID List:
"OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
Protocol Descriptor List:
"L2CAP" (0x0100)   
"RFCOMM" (0x0003)
Channel: 9 
"OBEX" (0x0008)
Profile Descriptor List:
"OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
Version: 0x0100
```

So How can manage to retrive data from this device?

Comment: Did you checkout: http://gitorious.org/android-obex

Comment: Also checkout: http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in the last link the guy made the server on the pc, I need to apply this server-side functionality to my android phone.

Comment: The first link mentions server on Android... http://gitorious.org/android-obex/pages/Home

Comment: Yeah! I know, already read that. But your phone needs to have root access.

Comment: You did not mention that in your original question.